# How can I restore some mysqldump files to my local Joomla database?

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin

I have these exported databases as mysqldump files. I have to restore them to my local Joomla server. The problem is that they are not have `.sql` format and I cannot import them to the Joomla database via the phpmyadmin dashboard because I get the message `Incorrect format parameter`. Also since there are multiple databases how am I supposed to set them up as a Joomla website.
Also I am using `Windows 10` and `XAMPP`.
This some of the CREATE and INSERT queries:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.44, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: athlitik_main
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.44

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `broadcasts`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `broadcasts`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `broadcasts` (
  `gid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gdate` date NOT NULL,
  `gtime` time NOT NULL,
  `gchannel` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `gmatch` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `gorg` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2244 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `broadcasts`
--

LOCK TABLES `broadcasts` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `broadcasts` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `broadcasts` VALUES (2234,'2015-01-30','18:30:00','Novasports 3 ','Παμβοχαϊκός - Εθνικός Αλεξανδρούπολης','League Cup - 1ος ημιτελικός'),(2235,'2015-01-30','21:00:00','Novasports 3 ','Ολυμπιακός - Άρης','League Cup - 2ος ημιτελικός'),(2236,'2015-01-30','21:30:00','OTE Sport 1 ','Βόλφσμπουργκ - Μπάγερν Μονάχου','Bundesliga'),(2237,'2015-01-30','21:30:00','Novasports 1 ','Παρί Σεν Ζερμέν - Ρεν','Ligue 1'),(2238,'2015-01-30','21:45:00','ΝΕΡΙΤ plus ','Παναθηναϊκός - Γαλατάσαραϊ','Euroleague'),(2239,'2015-01-30','21:45:00','Novasports 4 ','Μπαρτσελόνα - Ζαλγκίρις','Euroleague'),(2240,'2015-01-30','21:45:00','OTE Sport 2 ','Ράγιο Βαγιεκάνο - Ντεπορτίβο Λα Κορούνια','La Liga'),(2241,'2015-01-30','21:45:00','Novasports 2 ','Ουνικάχα Μάλαγα - Φενέρμπαχτσε','Euroleague'),(2242,'2015-01-31','02:30:00','OTE Sport 3 ','Μπρούκλιν Νετς - Τορόντο Ράπτορς','NBA'),(2243,'2015-01-31','10:30:00','Eurosport ','Αυστραλιανό Όπεν','Τελικός γυναικών');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `broadcasts` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `games`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `games`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `games` (
  `gid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gdate` date NOT NULL,
  `gtime` time NOT NULL,
  `gmatch` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `gorg` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `gstadium` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=707 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `games`
--

LOCK TABLES `games` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `games` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `games` VALUES (685,'2015-01-31','12:00:00','Α.Ο.ΧΑΝΙΑ-ΑΡΗΣ','Α\' ΕΘΝΙΚΗ ΓΥΝΑΙΚΩΝ','ΜΟΥΡΝΙΕΣ'),(686,'2015-02-02','15:30:00','Α..Ο.ΧΑΝΙΑ-ΦΩΣΤΗΡΑΣ','Κ-19 ΦΟΥΤΜΠΟΛ ΛΙΓΚ','ΑΓ.ΑΠΟΣΤΟΛΟΙ'),(687,'2015-01-31','15:00:00','ΗΡΑΚΛΗΣ ΝΕΡ.-ΑΡΗΣ ΒΟΥΚ.','Α\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΝΕΡΟΚΟΥΡΟΥ'),(688,'2015-01-31','15:00:00','ΠΑΝΑΚΡΩΤΗΡΙΑΚΟΣ-ΜΙΝΩΤΑΥΡΟΣ','Α\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΚΑΘΙΑΝΑ'),(689,'2015-01-31','15:00:00','ΑΡΗΣ Σ.-ΚΟΡΩΝΙΔΑ','Α\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΣΟΥΔΑ'),(690,'2015-01-31','15:00:00','ΣΠΑΘΑ-ΙΝΚΑ','Α\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΚΟΛΥΜΠΑΡΙ'),(691,'2015-01-31','15:00:00','ΔΟΞΑ-ΚΕΡΑΜΕΙΑ','Α\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΜΟΝ.ΕΛΙΑ'),(692,'2015-01-31','15:00:00','ΤΙΤΑΝ-ΠΑΓΧΑΝΙΑΚΟΣ','Α\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΝΙΟ ΧΩΡΙΟ'),(693,'2015-01-31','15:00:00','ΑΣΠΙΔΑ-ΑΣΤΕΡΑΣ ΜΑΝ.','Α\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΝΑΥΣΤΑΘΜΟΣ'),(694,'2015-02-01','15:00:00','ΔΑΑΟΧ-ΙΚΑΡΟΣ Μ.','Α\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΑΓ.ΑΠΟΣΤΟΛΟΙ'),(695,'2015-02-01','15:00:00','ΡΟΔΩΠΟΥ-ΙΔΟΜΕΝΕΑΣ','Α\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΚΟΛΥΜΠΑΡΙ'),(696,'2015-02-01','15:00:00','ΙΩΝΙΑ-ΠΑΛΑΙΟΧΩΡΑ','Α\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΜΟΝ.ΕΛΙΑ'),(697,'2015-01-31','15:00:00','ΔΑΦΝΗ-ΚΡ.ΑΣΤΕΡΑΣ','Β\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΕΜΠΡΟΣΝΕΡΟ'),(698,'2015-02-01','10:30:00','ΦΩΣΤΗΡΑΣ-ΧΑΛΗΣ','Β\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΝΕΡΟΚΟΥΡΟΥ'),(699,'2015-02-01','10:30:00','ΑΜΙΛΛΑ-ΑΠΟΛΛΩΝ','Β\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΠΛΑΤΑΝΙΑΣ'),(700,'2015-02-01','10:30:00','ΘΥΕΛΛΑ ΚΑΛ.-ΓΡΑΝΙΤΗΣ','Β\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΚΑΣΤΕΛΙ'),(701,'2015-02-01','15:00:00','Ν.ΣΑΜΨΩΝ-ΑΠΤΕΡΑ','Β\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΝΙΟ ΧΩΡΙΟ'),(702,'2015-02-01','15:00:00','ΠΟΣΕΙΔΩΝ ΤΣ.-ΑΕ ΚΥΔΩΝΙΑΣ','Β\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΣΟΥΔΑ'),(703,'2015-02-01','15:00:00','ΙΚΑΡΟΣ ΤΑΥΡ.-ΠΕΡΙΒΟΛΙΑ','Β\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΤΑΥΡΩΝΙΤΗΣ'),(704,'2015-01-31','15:00:00','Ν.ΚΙΣΑΜΙΚΟΣ-ΥΡΤΑΚΙΝΑ','Γ\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΚΑΣΤΕΛΙ'),(705,'2015-02-04','15:00:00','Ν.ΗΡΑΚΛΗΣ Ν.-ΤΑΛΩΣ','Γ\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΝΕΡΟΚΟΥΡΟΥ'),(706,'2015-02-04','15:00:00','Α.Π.ΣΟΥΔΑΣ-Ν.ΜΙΝΩΤΑΥΡΟΥ','Γ\' ΕΠΣΧ','ΣΟΥΔΑ');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `games` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Show us a bit of your CREATE and INSERT queries so that we have some context.  Is this a joomla prefixing issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.sql` to the dump filenames.